# Find the closest fraction to a decimal with a specific denominator using Python's fractions module

Tags: python, fractions

With Python's `fractions` module I can do something like:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> import math
>>> target_number = str( 10 / math.pi )
>>> Fraction( target_number )
Fraction(39788735773, 12500000000)
```

But what should I do if I want a fraction in sixteenths? That is, `Fraction(51, 16)`. Using `limit_denominator(16)` only makes the maximum denominator 16:

```
>>> Fraction( target_number ).limit_denominator(16)
Fraction(35, 11)
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this with the `fractions` module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's straightforward to calculate the numerator you need without the `fractions` module -- it's just the nearest integer to `16*target_number` -- and if you want a `Fraction` then you can (and should) just say (without stringifying your target number, of course):

```
Fraction(int(round(16*target_number)),16)
```

(It looks, empirically, as if omitting the `int()` doesn't stop it working, but according to the docs you're supposed to pass rational numbers in.)

Comment: My thoughts exactly! However, leaving out `int()` gives me a `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index` in 2.6, and `TypeError: both arguments should be Rational Instances` in 2.7 and 3.2

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> target = 10 / math.pi
>>> denominator = 16
>>> fractions.Fraction(int(round(target*denominator)), denominator)
Fraction(51, 16)
```